# How to Retrieve a List from Firebase using a spinner?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, spinner

So I am trying to retrieve a list  of all the items based on the sector spinner, because some items belong to different sectors, and I want to display the cases that belong in a specific sector

[image: Tree View]

I have two classes one that stores the status and date the other stores the location
Location Class

```
public class Location {

    public String sector;
    public String area;

    public double longitude;
    public double latitude;

    public String getSector() {
        return sector;
    }

    public String getArea() {
        return area;
    }

    public double getLongitude() {
        return longitude;
    }

    public double getLatitude() {
        return latitude;
    }

    public Location()
    {

    }

    public Location(String sector , String area, double longitude, double latitude)
    {
        this. sector = sector;
        this. area = area;
        this.longitude = longitude;
        this.latitude = latitude;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "\n Sector='" + sector + '\'' +
                ",Area Name='" + area + '\'' +
                ",Longitude='" + longitude + '\'' +
                ",Latitude=" + latitude + "\n";

    }
```

Case Class

```
public class Case {

    public String date;
    public String caseStatus;

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public String getCaseStatus() {
        return caseStatus;
    }

    public Case()
    {

    }

    public Case(String date,String caseStatus)
    {
        this.date = date;
        this.caseStatus = caseStatus;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "\nCase Date='" + date + '\'' +
                ",Case Status='" + caseStatus + "\n";

    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?

Comment: I want a solution where i can select a sector using a spinner and display a list with items that have matching sectors

Comment: It doesn't look like you've made any attempt to query the database or populate your data objects.  I suggest starting with the documentation to learn how to get data. https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add Location to the Case class. Also you should make variables private.

```
public class Case {

    private Date date;
    private String status;
    private Location location;

    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public Location getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

    public Case() {
    }

    public Case(Date date, String status, Location location) {
        this.date = date;
        this.status = status;
        this.location = location;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "\nCase Date='" + date + '\'' +
                ",Case Status='" + status + "\n";

    }
}
```

Open Firestore and start a project.
Connect it to Android Studio in Tools > Firebase > Firestore.
Use String for status, Timestamp for date and Map for location

[image: how it should look like in your case]

Add this code to your project.

```
    ArrayList<Case> cases = new ArrayList<>();
    
    FirebaseFirestore firestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    firestore.collection("cases")
    .whereEqualTo("location.sector", "somesector")
    .get()
    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                            Case case = document.toObject(Case.class);
                            cases.add(case);
// now you have list of Case objects where sector equals "somesector"
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
```

How to add Case to Firestore collection:

```
Case case = new Case(new Date(), "positive", new Location("somesector", "somearea", 150d, 555d));

FirebaseFirestore firestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
firestore.collection("cases").add(case);
```

Comment: but if i am trying to access data from firebase, should I not use DataSnapshot?

Comment: and i don't want to store the list in a spinner, just want to retrieve the list based the sector is chose from the spinner

Comment: please, consider using firestore if you want to do queries. Check my updated answer

Comment: Is it possible if you can provide me with a way to insert data in firestore, because i am bit lost on how I can add an object in firestore

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore this official tutorial should help you

Comment: The Solution you provided displays everything correctly except for the Status where it is always displayed as null, I appreciate your time in helping me, but if you can just provide me an insert method for the data and a fix it will be very much appreciated

Comment: I have fixed Case object, status won't be null now. It was null because it was named `status` in firestore and `caseStatus` in the app. It matters. I will add put method a bit later to my answer

Comment: I have added method, hope it is ok now and you have no trouble

Comment: Mr.Vasia you have been very helpful, everything works fine and I hope you have a safe life

Comment: Thank you! Good luck in future development